# Send an xmpp message using a python library

Tags: python, xmpp

How can I send an XMPP message using one of the following Python libraries: wokkel, xmpppy, or jabber.py ?

I think I am aware of the pseudo-code, but so far have not been able to get one running correctly.  This is what I have tried so far:

- Call some API and pass the servername and port number to connect to that server.
- Call some API and pass the username, password to construct a JID object.
- Authenticate with that JID.
- Construct a Message object and call some API and pass that message obj in the argument.
- Call some send API.

It seems easy enough in concept, but the devil is somewhere in the details.  Please show a sample snippet if that's possible.

Answer (score 40):

This is the simplest possible xmpp client. It will send a 'hello :)' message. I'm using [`xmpppy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmpppy) in the example. And connecting to gtalk server. I think the example is self-explanatory:

```
import xmpp

username = 'username'
passwd = 'password'
to='name@example.com'
msg='hello :)'


client = xmpp.Client('gmail.com')
client.connect(server=('talk.google.com',5223))
client.auth(username, passwd, 'botty')
client.sendInitPresence()
message = xmpp.Message(to, msg)
message.setAttr('type', 'chat')
client.send(message)
```

Comment: Clearly something is wrong about these packages... I already had xmpp installed but it didn't have Client inside. I installed xmpppy and I still get the same error. Clearly a bad idea to release packages with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

[xmpppy](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/) has a number of examples listed on its main page (under "examples"), the most basic of which [sends a single test message](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/examples/README.py). They make the examples progressively more interesting -- they introduce the callback-oriented API via a [chat bot program](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/examples/xtalk.py).