# XMPP, openfire and bot issue

Tags: java, php, python, xmpp

**I am interested to make a chatbot. My script is currently working fine with imified.com bot. however imified is down almost everday. so i am looking for my own solution.**

during my findings, I have found (through this site) openfire and I have configured it and it is working fine even with gmails users.

but i am still not getting what I need.

**I need to request a URL (with the chat scripts and some other user data something like imified provides) when each gmail or other external users send me a message. let me explain.**

my openfire is hosted and working for mybot.com and my id is: autobot@mybot.com.

now a gmail user say client@gmail.com added me in his gtalk/piding and we can communicate each other. he can send me message and I can reply.

but I need a robot instead of me. when client@gmail.com (and any other user) sends me a message, I need to request a URL so that i can dynamically generate response based on the message he/she sent.

**in which way I should go for achieving this? Is there any way to customize openfire to do so?**

**or should I make a php/python (i need to learn python though) script that will listen to xmpp ports and generate responses? if so, any helpful scripts that may guide me?**

bunch of thanks for reading it and thanks in advance for providing any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenFire understand XMPP, what you need is XMPP library/API (like XMPP4R if you are Rubyist). Using it your app will login to OpenFire (by sending gmail/yahoo credentials) and others will see you as online. But when they will reply to you, you will be notified in your application. Where you can receive the message, process it, and send response (by writing a required program/logic).

We have done it in our SMS Chat application with Gmail/Yahoo messenger friends/contacts.

Comment: Thanks Asif for your input! Do you know any good php or python library like XMPP4R? while you answer, i'm asking it to Google :).

Comment: hi Asif, i think this thread gonna help me :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910737/send-an-xmpp-message-using-a-python-library

Comment: I didn't used XMPP with PHP/Python. If you have got it, I wish you good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Openfire is XMPP-server. It's route messages between XMPP-clients.

You need XMPP-client which connects to server and process messages from other clients.

For example you can look [here](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/). That page contains two simple bots.

Comment: Hi,I am still open for other responses too :).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use xmpp js lib 'strophe'

https://github.com/metajack/strophejs

and the xmpp python  lib

https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP

and the xmpp php lib

https://github.com/alexmace/Xmpp

have a try and good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try out our XMPP chat bot, it has been tested with openfire : 
http://github.com/gbin/err

It is super easy to setup, and making a minimal hello world plugin is quite easy, no need to manipulate XMPP : 
see https://gist.github.com/2902497