# In need of a python script to upload a file with IP address every few minutes

Tags: python, ip-address, autorun

I'm using windows server 2008, and one of the things I need to do in order to pair to a domain name is send a file with the computers current IP address (it's not static) to a server via sftp every few minutes. The problem is that I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Whats digesting the file?  There has to be a more streamlined way then secure transferring a file thats wrapped in a protocol, that in itself, has the data you want.

Comment: I would love to hear that there is, but I can't think of any way.

Comment: I'd just listen on an obscure UDP socket for inbound datagrams.  The payload can be the hostname; the IP address can be obtained from the header.  If security is an issue, just sign the payload- encryption is of no use as the info you want (the ip) is in the IP header anyway. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/Network/UDPExample.htm

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to change that script to do what I want, when I enter the host name (x.com), it says " 'x' is not defined ". Also, wouldn't that be my internal IP?

Comment: Hostnames are strings so they need to be wrapped in quotes 'x.com'.  If you've never used Python before, it would do you well learn the language before trying to build a network tool.  http://www.diveintopython.org/

Comment: Any reason you aren't using one of the many Dynamic DNS services available?

Comment: Andrew you're right! Thank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would send it via XMPP.  You can set up a listener service for the server.

[Send an xmpp message using a python library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910737/send-an-xmpp-message-using-a-python-library)

Here are some ideas on XMPP servers to run on your IIS server (listening to recieve the incoming messages from clients http://metajack.im/2008/08/26/choosing-an-xmpp-server/

[Pretzel](http://code.google.com/p/pretzel/) looks nice

this python code can be run client side to get the public IP address.

```
host, aliaslist, lan_ip = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
print host
print aliaslist
print lan_ip[0]
```

Than you would send via XMPP message containing the IP to the server you have set up on your IIS server.   Depending on what you want to do with the IP address once it gets to the server, you will handle the message serverside

Comment: So now I understand how sending it would work, but would you elaborate on listeners? I'm not quite sure how to use those to get the IP address.